# Creating reusable widgets with javascript

Tags: jquery, design-patterns, widget, javascript

I'm working on creating small, embeddable widgets which have a handle outside of their own JS files.

**Page Structure**

For example, I have a page which may contain n-number of '**power-widget**'s in it. 'n' is determined by the web server serving the page. 
A '**power-widget**' is nothing but a div with the name of a device and it's current power consumption on it. The current reading is updated via ajax every 5 secs.

NOTE: Each page can have different 'types' of widgets, though the image below has only one type of widget.
[image: screen of what I created without using widgets]

**The Widget**

Each green box is a widget which is initialized on page load and takes the device name, color etc as the parameters. Each **type** of widget, '**power-widget**' in this case, has its own JS and CSS files (along with the HTML structure) which are loaded asynchronously once the page detects that those are required.
Hence, the same widget can be rendered on any page within my website.

**The Problem**

I have written code to detect and load the required JS, CSS and HTML content of each widget and place it in it's desired div. I wrote some code to create a 'class-like' structure for the widget which I can instantiate and write methods (like updating the readings) in.

```
function PowerStatus(options) {
    this.settings = {
        meterName: '',
        mainDiv: null,
        glow: false,
        meterOn: "#91bd09",
        meterOff: "#bc330d",
        meterMid: "#333333"
    };
    this.settings = $.extend(this.settings, options);
    this.settings.mainDiv = $('#' + this.settings.mainDiv);
    this.bindUIActions();
    this.setMeterName();
}

PowerStatus.prototype.setMeterName = function () {
    console.log(this.settings.mainDiv);
    var div = this.settings.mainDiv.find('.load-name');
    var span = $('span:first', div);
    span.text(this.settings.meterName);
};

PowerStatus.prototype.bindUIActions = function () {
    this.settings.mainDiv.on("click", this.divclick);
};

PowerStatus.prototype.divclick = function () {
    console.log(this);
    console.log('Clicked ' + this.settings.meterName);
};
```

The page inside which the widgets have to be placed calls the following code

```
var widget = new PowerStatus({meterName: 'Widget 1', mainDiv: 'widget-power-status-1'});
```

for all the widgets, thereby getting a handle on each.

In the above code, when I click on the div, it throws a

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'meterName' of undefined

because the callee (**this**) being passed is actually a 'div' element and not the PowerStatus object. Any clue what's going on? Is jQuery passing it's selected div?
Also, I wanted to know if this is the cleanest way to go about the entire thing. I'm pretty new to JS and would welcome any advice.

Answer (score 4):

You need to create an object constructor rather than using object literals.

```
function PowerStatus( opts ) {

  this.init = function( opts ){

  }

}
```

Then:

```
var widget = new PowerStatus( opts );
widget.init();
```

Comment: Would angular.js make this easier, in general?

Comment: i updated the code as you suggested - it looks good but there's another problem - I've updated the question.

Comment: EmberJS (my personal pref)/AngularJS/KnockOut etc, will make these sort of tasks easier but like any new tech would require you learn the framework.

As far as your new code goes, I can't see where you're setting meterName in your PowerStatus object? BTW - best practice on StackO is to create a new question so other can find your old question and learn as well. :)

Comment: meterName is just an attribute of the PowerStatus class. I will use it to set the text inside the <span> element of the widget as well as while querying for the updated readings.
Any idea on why 'this' of JS is being overshadowed by the 'this' of jQuery?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed replies, quite busy today: Basically, `PowerStatus.prototype.setMeterName` should be `this.setMeterName = function()`. This will allow you to call `this.setMeterName()` as well as `widget.setMeterName()`.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time out. :)
I have made some progress and posted it in another question, as you suggested. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22923341/javascript-nested-dictionary-null-values