# Javascript nested dictionary null values

Tags: javascript, jquery, dictionary, nullreferenceexception

Below I have declared a 'class' in JS and am writing methods for it. The class represents a widget ([more info class structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22914385/creating-reusable-widgets-with-javascript/22915642?noredirect=1#comment34987056_22915642)).

The problem I'm having is that when I print 'this' inside the setAttr ibutes method, the output is:
[image]

And when I print  'this.opts' in the very next line:
[image]

**NOTE**: The values of 'status' and 'power' are shown as 'null' in the second output before expanding it. This can be the only possible reason behind getting 'null' while trying to print 'this.opts.status'.

**CODE**

```
function PowerStatus(options) {
    this.opts = {
        meterName: '-',
        displayName: null,
        status: null,
        power: null,
        mainDiv: null,
    };
    this.opts = $.extend(this.opts, options);
    this.opts.mainDiv = '#' + this.opts.mainDiv;
    this.onClick = function () {
        console.log('Clicked ' + this.opts.meterName);
    };

    // fill in missing attributes
    this.getAttributes();
    this.setHtml();
    this.bindUIActions();
}

PowerStatus.prototype.getAttributes = function () {
    var _this = this;
    if (this.opts.displayName == null) {
        getDisplayName(function (dName) {
            _this.opts.displayName = dName;
        }, _this.opts.meterName);
    }
    if (_this.opts.status == null || _this.opts.power == null) {
        _this.getStatus(function (status, power) {
            _this.opts.status = status;
            _this.opts.power = power;
        }, _this.opts.meterName)
    }
};

PowerStatus.prototype.setHtml = function () {
    var _this = this;
    var divType = this.opts.mainDiv.split('-').slice(1).slice(0, -1).join('_');
    var url = '/static/' + divType + '/html/' + divType + '.html';

    $(this.opts.mainDiv).load(url, function () {
        _this.setAttributes();
    });
};


PowerStatus.prototype.setAttributes = function () {
    var div = $(this.opts.mainDiv).find('.load-name');
    var span = $('span:first', div);
    span.text(this.opts.displayName);

    div = $(this.opts.mainDiv).find('.load-value');
    span = $('span:first', div);
    span.text(this.opts.power);
};

PowerStatus.prototype.bindUIActions = function () {
    var _this = this;
    $(this.opts.mainDiv).on('click', function () {
        _this.onClick();
    });
};

PowerStatus.prototype.getStatus = function (callback) {
    $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "/widget/power_status/status/",
        data: {name: this.opts.meterName},
        success: function (data) {
            if (typeof callback === "function") callback(data.status, data.power);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The value of `this` inside your click handler is not the same as the value *outside* that handler.  You need to stash `this` in a local variable and use that instead.

```
var statusObj = this;
this.onClick = function () {
    console.log('Clicked ' + statusObj.opts.meterName);
};
```

Alternatively, you could use `.bind()`:

```
this.onClick = function () {
    console.log('Clicked ' + this.opts.meterName);
}.bind(this);
```

The value of `this` is *always* set on *every* individual call to a function based on the circumstances of the call.

Comment: I made the changes. However, the problem is not with the onClick method. Is there something wrong with how I have handled 'this' in the other methods?

Comment: @vinayakshukl so you're saying that when you update those `<span>` elements you get `null`?

Comment: @vinayakshukl oh wait; I think I see the problem. Or at least I see *a* problem.

Comment: @vinayakshukl I have to do something in the real world, but I'll return to this later if you don't have an answer yet.

Comment: Yea, somehow the console shows the correct value in the collapsed form but when I open the dictionary, it shows a null. 
Sure, I'll be waiting for your answer. o.O